# How to redeploy a site using git?

Tags: git

I'm using a post-receive hook in git to upload changes to my website:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

(based on this link: http://toroid.org/git-website-howto)

It works fine, but once in a while something that I don't know happens and part of the files are deleted.

so, I have two questions:

1. does anybody know why would this happen?
2. how can i redeploy an entire site (not just the commit changes) using a git command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it would happen, but, regarding "redeploying an entire site (not just the commit changes) using a git command", you could use [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) instead.

If you don't have any private files, you can do a `reset --hard`:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git reset --hard
```

Comment: thanks, that really worked. i ran it as a command in ssh, and everything started to work again. turns out something changed permissions on my files, so `post-receive` was not running.